# How to constrain rigid bodies to an axis?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

In the game engine there is an option to constrain rigid body translations and rotations on an axis:

[image]

Is it possible to do this with the 3D view rigid body physics system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In blender 2.80 (and likely earlier versions), you can selectively lock translation and rotation axes, limiting physics simulations to your choosing.

Do this in the Transform sidebar (hit N to toggle).

[image]

As seen above, both X and Y axis has been locked, forcing simulation to only translate along Z-axis, but otherwise rotate freely.

This can be handy for quickly placing objects using physics. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is currently supported **only** in the Game Engine.

As a possible workaround, you could bake the simulation to keyframes and then remove the transform channels which you don't want.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for 2.69? I have the same question as gandalf3. The slider constraint is too complicated.

Comment: Also your alternative doesn't really work as a solution since the axis restrictions work on the solver per-frame. Disabling rotation on all three axes would prevent a ball from rolling down a hill for example.