# How do you allow an object to rotate around an axis?

Tags: rigidbody

I am trying to create a wind turbine and I am wondering how to allow the blades to spin freely during the animation.  To specify,  I have a wind force field and a base with the blades of the turbine connected to  a rotor.  Here is an image:[image]
I want the animation to start and when the wind blows I want the blades to spin but not fly away.  I would think that you need to use a rigid body constraint but after trying all the types it still flies away.  I am using blender 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier to animate it, use shift + axis.[image]

add a key-frame where it should start with the desired rotation, and then add other key frames where you want the 'fan' to turn and the angle of choice. (i chosen 359 because im not sure if i set it to 360 it would just not move, but go ahead and experiment! )
[image]

blender will automatically interpolate the key frames you set.

but if you really want accurate physics then im afraid i also don't know :(

**but maybe this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5816/how-to-constrain-rigid-bodies-to-an-axis) will help.**

Comment: I don't want to make the animation myself. I want it to be like the object selected is rotating around the axis as if you clicked R but I want the wind to actually spin the turbine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints in the Object Constraints tab.  Make sure you tick 'Affect Transform', and limit rotation in specific axes.

[image]

[image: Gif]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A rigid body constraint that allows rotation in a single axis and allows no translation is a "hinge" type constraint, although this behavior can also be replicated with a "generic spring."  The hinge constraint allows rotation in only the Z axis of the rigid body constraint.  However, most rigid body constraints allow no translation, so if your object is flying away, it's probably not just the particular type of constraint you're using, but the settings for that constraint.

Here are settings I would use on a rigid body constraint for your purpose:

[image]

Note:

1. The Z axis of the rigid body constraint is oriented to point in the axis of allowed rotation.
2. The rigid body constraint connects *two* objects.  The first object is a passive or animated rigid body, which acts as an anchor, while the second object is the dynamic fan.

Other issues that can cause rigid bodies to fly away include backwards normals, improper collision types, intersecting collisions at frame 1, and unapplied scale.

All that said, this is a good place to repeat myself that **Blender physics are not real physics.**  The fact that this fan would spin in a real world wind does not mean that it will spin in a Blender wind.  Rigid body physics are a highly simplified abstration of real world physics, and they don't create rotational force from wind.